# Doxygen and @ORM annotated entities in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine, doxygen

I have implemented entities within the Symfony2 framework that are annotated to be used by Doctrine. For example:

```
/*
 * class description
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Website\ContentBundle\Repository\ContentRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"article" = "Article"})
 * @ORM\Table(name="content",indexes={@ORM\index(name="id_UNIQUE",columns={"id"})})
 */
 class Content {
    /** 
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    ...
  }
```

When I run Doxygen on my source code, the documentation is not very readable. I have tried to define aliases for each @ORM* symbol; for example "ORM=ORM", "Entity=Entity", and so on. But this does not work. For the above mentioned class Doxygen returns

```
...
ORMEntity(repositoryClass="Website\ContentBundle\Repository\ContentRepository") ORM() ORM("SINGLE_TABLE") ORM(name="type", type="string") ORM({"article" = "Article", "picture_series" = "PictureSeries", "event" = "Event", "invitation" = "Invitation"}) ORMTable(name="content",indexes={ORM(name="id_UNIQUE",columns={"id"})})
```

With respect to method

```
/**
* sets the given id 
* 
* @param number $id
* @return \Website\ContentBundle\Entity\Content
*/
public function setId($id) {
    $this->id = $id;
    return $this; // fluent interface
}
```

Doxygen creates

```
setId ($ id)    
   sets the given id

Parameters:
    number  $id 

Returns:
```

Why does it not show the \Website\ContentBundle\Entity\Content after "Returns:"?

Maybe someone can give me a hint or a link on how to configure Doxygen such that it can handle the @ORM annotations appropriately.

THX in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With respect to the question

> Why does it not show the `\Website\ContentBundle\Entity\Content` after `Returns:`?

This is probably because doxygen commands start with a `\`, do doxygen thinks you are calling some commands which it does not recognise, and so presumably strips from the documentation and does nothing with.

You were on the right line with attempting to use the `ALIASES` configuration file option. However, instead of defining `ORM=ORM` try using `ORM=\@ORM`. I got your example source code to be documented by doxygen without any warnings by defining the following aliases:

```
ALIASES  = "ORM=\@ORM"  
ALIASES += "Entity=\\Entity"  
ALIASES += "InheritanceType=\\InheritanceType"  
ALIASES += "DiscriminatorColumn=\\DiscriminatorColumn"  
ALIASES += "DiscriminatorMap=\\DiscriminatorMap"  
ALIASES += "Table=\\Table"  
ALIASES += "Id=\\Id"  
ALIASES += "Column=\\Column"  
ALIASES += "GeneratedValue=\\GeneratedValue"  
ALIASES += "index=\\index"  
ALIASES += "HasLifecycleCallbacks=\\HasLifecycleCallbacks"  
ALIASES += "Repository=\\Repository"  
ALIASES += "ContentRepository=\\ContentRepository"  
ALIASES += "ContentBundle=\\ContentBundle"  
ALIASES += "Website=\\Website"  
ALIASES += "Content=\\Content"
```

Here [`\\`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdbackslash), [`\@`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdat) are actually doxygen commands for printing the backslash `\` and `@` characters respectively.

Note, however, that the `@ORM...` directives will all appear on the same line. I'm not sure how to avoid this (*update*: see my edit below). Does anyone else have any ideas?

Finally, as a side note, your documentation for `$id` should be

```
* @param $id number
```

note the order of `$id` and `number`. See the documentation for [`\param`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdparam).

**Edit**: An alternative way of doing this would be to wrap the Doctrine relavent parts in [`\verbatim`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdverbatim) and `\endverbatim` tags. This will preserve the line breaks in your class description which will be more readable.

Comment: It works great! Regarding your comment on how to document a parameter. I chose "my" notation because (1) in Symfony2 almost every method is documented that way and (2) it is more readable when describing the parameter as well. @param $id number description is not that readable, I think.

Comment: Glad I could help. To anyone who is used to doxygen the notion `\param variable "variable description"` is far more readable. Regardless, this is how `\param` is defined in doxygen - so you are using it wrong and the documentation will not reflect what is actually going on in the code. Furthermore, doxygen will issue warnings with your way. I strongly recommend using `\param` how it is defined in the doxygen manual.

Comment: I know that I am somehow using it the wrong way. However, in PHP, the parameter list of a method does not show the type of each parameter. As such, I think, that the parameter type must be reflected in the doc.